# What's The Correct Way To Set Src Attribute In JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<img id="foo" src="bar1.jpg"/>
```

I would like to switch the `src` to `bar2.jpg`

Can I just do this?

```
$("#foo").attr("src", "bar2.jpg");
```

Or do I have to do this?

```
$("#foo").removeAttr("src");
$("#foo").attr("src", "bar2.jpg");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$("#foo").attr("src", "bar2.jpg");
```

The previous `src` is replaced.

So you don't need:

```
$("#foo").removeAttr("src");
```

---

### [You can confirm it out here](http://jsbin.com/ekeru4#)

Answer (score 6):

Just do `.attr('src', 'foo')` because you're assigning a `src` regardless. Only remove the attribute if you don't need it entirely.

Answer (score 6):

The first wey is just fine, no reason to remove it first.

```
$("#foo").attr("src", "bar2.jpg");
```

$.attr serves both to get the existing attribute and to change it (depending on whether theres one or two arguments).  Your situation is exactly what he second functionality is intended for, and the attribute 'src' is not special.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.main{
    position:relative;
}
.second{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:720px;
}
.third{
    position:absolute;
top:290px;
left:720px;
}
.fourth{
    position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:1030px;
}
.firstarrow{
    position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:1100px;
}
.secondarrow{
    position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:1030px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".firstarrow").on('click', function() {
   var pos1 = $('.first img').attr('src');
   var pos2 = $('.second img').attr('src');
   var pos3 = $('.third img').attr('src');
   var pos4 = $('.fourth img').attr('src');
   $('.third img').attr('src', pos1);
   $('.fourth img').attr('src', pos3);
   $('.second img').attr('src', pos4);
   $('.first img').attr('src', pos2);
});

  $(".secondarrow").on('click', function() {
   var pos1 = $('.first img').attr('src');
   var pos2 = $('.second img').attr('src');
   var pos3 = $('.third img').attr('src');
   var pos4 = $('.fourth img').attr('src');
   $('.third img').attr('src', pos4);
   $('.fourth img').attr('src', pos2);
   $('.second img').attr('src', pos1);
   $('.first img').attr('src', pos3);
});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="first">
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="" width="700" height="511" />
</div>
<div class="second">
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="250" />
</div>
<div class="third">
<img src="img3.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="250" />
</div>
<div class="fourth">
<img src="img4.jpg" align="" width="300" height="400"  />
</div>
<a href="#"><div class="firstarrow"><img src="ar1.jpg" width="48" height="48" /></div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="secondarrow"><img src="ar2.jpg" width="48" height="48" /></div></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even for `mediaelement` player have:

```
  $("#player5").attr("poster", "/images/poster/Azadi.jpg");
```