# How to put value into scr

Tags: jquery, selector

I need to take a value of href from link, and put that value into scr of source selector.

```
<source src="HERE should be value" type="audio/mpeg">
```

my code

```
 <div id="music">
    <a href="horse.mp3">taken</a>
 </div>
 <audio controls>
   <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#music a').click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var value = $(this).attr('href');
            $('p').html("<p>"+value+"</p>");
            $('source').html("<source[scr$="+value+"</source>");

        });
    });
</script>
```

Purpose 1.mp3 should be swop with hourse.mp3

My code doesn't work, the value of the scr is not changing
Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's The Correct Way To Set Src Attribute In JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390627/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-src-attribute-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `src` attribute in direct way:

```
$('source').attr("src", value);
```

[***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/es1no0mo/)

To preload the audio from the new source use **audio|video.load()** function:

```
$('#music a').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        $('p').html("<p>" + value + "</p>");
        $('source').attr("src", value);

        // document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].load(); // pure JS approach
        $('audio')[0].load();  // to preload the audio from the new source
        $('audio')[0].play();  // to play the audio immediately

});
```

Comment: Thank ypu, but player doesnot play without refreshing page, can you help?

Comment: I tried , but without any success. Can you show how it looks in my code,thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you have here:

```
$('p').html("<p>"+value+"</p>");
$('source').html("<source[scr$="+value+"</source>");
```

Is not *replacing* the tag like you expect. It is inserting the html *inside* the existing element.

To change the attr only:

```
$('p').html(value);
$('source').attr("src", value);
```

Note also the src/scr typo.